# C++ Boost - __assert_fail was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, boost, raspberry-pi, g++, boost-filesystem

Currently I am developing library that will be used on Raspberry Pi 3. To loop through all files in a directory I decided to use `boost::filesystem` module. I have prepared this code:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

boost::filesystem::path targetDir(some_path);
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(targetDir), eod;

BOOST_FOREACH(boost::filesystem::path const& p, std::make_pair(it, eod))
{
    if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p))
    {
        // do smth with file
    }
}
```

Boost has been installed through `apt-get install libboost1.62-all-dev`.

Unfortunately compiling in Visual Studio 2017 (on remote RPi target, g++ 4.9.2) gives me this bunch of errors:

```
__assert_fail was not declared in this scope (path_trails.hpp)
...
__assert_fail was not declared in this scope (path.hpp)
...
__assert_fail was not declared in this scope (shared_ptr.hpp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Boost can fail on bleeding edge compilers since the release cycle is very slow.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi What do you mean by that? I will not be able to run boost on RPi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not connected with boost. I had `#include <Magick++.h>` line above and this causes these output errors. After commenting this line everything runs fine, now I need to find why Magick++ is causing this compability issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into what seems like the same issue.

What is strange is I did not see this issue in stretch or buster, only in bullseye. Were you using a version of imagemagick that did not come from the Raspbian archive?

In any case the issue in my case was that Magick++.h ends up include assert.h inside a namespace, when this happens it breaks any other code that tries to use assert.h

The workaround is to re-order your includes and/or add an explicit include of assert.h so that assert.h gets included before Magick++.h